# C# Add event to value inside Dictionary<TKey, TValue>

Tags: c#, dictionary, events

I'm trying to add an event to the value of a dictionary. I made my own ObservableDictionary with an event on the Add button, but now I'm trying to do the same for the value. The dictionary looks like `Dictionary<string, ObservableCollection<string>>`.

The calling function:

```
public void AddExtension(string key, string value)
{
    if (_settings.ExtensionsPerFolder.ContainsKey(key))
    {
        _settings.ExtensionsPerFolder[key].Add(value);
        var values = _settings.ExtensionsPerFolder[key];
        values.Add(value);
        _settings.ExtensionsPerFolder[key] = values;
    }
    else
        _settings.ExtensionsPerFolder.Add(key, new ObservableCollection<string> { value });
}
```

My own dictionary implementation:

```
public class ObservableDictionary<TKey, TValue> : Dictionary<TKey, TValue>
{
    public event EventHandler CollectionChanged;

    public new TValue this[TKey key]
    {
        get => base[key];
        set
        {
            base[key] = value;
            OnCollectionChanged();
        }
    }

    public new void Add(TKey key, TValue value)
    {
        base.Add(key, value);
        OnCollectionChanged();
    }

    protected void OnCollectionChanged() => CollectionChanged?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
}
```

The `_settings.ExtensionsPerFolder[key].Add(value)` doesn't trigger the `OnCollectionChanged` event, but the `_settings.ExtensionsPerFolder[key] = values` does.

[EDIT] The file in which the Dictionary is initialized:

```
public class Settings
    {
        [JsonIgnore]
        public string SettingsPath { get; } = "Settings.json";
        public ObservableCollection<string> Directories { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<string>();
        public ObservableDictionary<string, ObservableCollection<string>> ExtensionsPerFolder { get; set; } = new ObservableDictionary<string, ObservableCollection<string>>();

        public Settings() { }

        public void CollectionChanged()
        {
            Directories.CollectionChanged += CollectionChanged;
            ExtensionsPerFolder.CollectionChanged += CollectionChanged;
        }

        private void CollectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                using StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(SettingsPath);
                writer.WriteLine(this.ToJson());
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Logger log = new Logger();
                log.Log($"Unable to save: {ex.ToString()}");
            }
        }
    }
```

Is there any way that I can achieve this power of event control, or do I have to fiddle with the Add functionality within my own Dictionary for it to work.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show the declaration (the type) of `ExtensionsPerFolder` please?

Comment: @Wyck I've edited the post to include the file in which uses the `ExtensionsPerFolder`

Comment: Well, it seems that you'll need to subscribe to `CollectionChanged` event of every `ObservableCollection<string>` in dictionary value

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski and when adding a new Item to the dictionary, I should also subscribe to that ObservableCollection?

Comment: When I tried to recreate this this I get an error with `_settings.ExtensionsPerFolder.Add(key, new List<string> { value });` saying `cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.List<string>' to 'System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<string>'` because you're adding a `new List<string>` but I think you should be adding a `new ObservableCollection<string>` ... **and subscribing to it**.  Something's weird here....  How did the `List<string>` become an `ObservableCollection<string>`?

Comment: @Wyck that's because I made a mistake there, it is supposed to be an ObservableCollection<string>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a collection of collections and you've only ever subscribed to observe the outer collection.  You've subscribed to `ExtensionsPerFolder.CollectionChanged` which will tell you when you do something like `ExtensionsPerFolder[key] = values`, but you haven't subscribed to each inner collection.  In this case `values` should be an `ObservableCollection<string>`.

Each time you create a new `ObservableCollection<string>`, you'll want to subscribe to it.

Here's where you created a new one:

```
_settings.ExtensionsPerFolder.Add(key, new ObservableCollection<string> { value });
```

You'll also want to add a `CollectionChanged` handler for this new collection at this point in your code.  That way a statement like `_settings.ExtensionsPerFolder[key].Add(value)` will trigger a `CollectionChanged` event on that particular collection.

I'll leave it to you to decide what you want that event handler to do.

Comment: Thank you. Based on yours and PavelAnikhouski's comments I figured this out as well. Was hoping that something more.. sofisticated existed, but this will do just fine :)